# How to apply Kalman Filter to GDP data?

Tags: default-probability, macro-economics, kalman

Once reverted the Merton/Vasicek formula I could compute the $PD^{PIT}$ for IFRS9 as

$PD^{PIT}_i(z) = \Phi \left( \phi^{-1}(PD^{TTC}_i) \sqrt{1-\rho_i} + \sqrt{\rho_i}z\right)$

The main issue is to extract a proper set of scenario $z$ as it is not the GDP or any other observable quantity but rather a factor intrinsic of the model.

This [paper](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/-/media/boe/files/ccbs/resources/modelling-credit-risk.pdf?la=en&hash=53B7332226FB2FB1B280B3D643DBB8AFF1FA5F32) of BoE suggests to use the Kalman filter that seems really appropriate in this context.

I am struggling figuring how to apply the Kalman filter as I am not using it since the Signals exam at university.

How should procedure work?

Should I consider the hts of an observable variable (eg. GDP) and extrapolate this hidden state from that?

Comment: Have you already inspected resources such as this: https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/22734/1/KalmanFilter.pdf ?

Comment: still not very clear